# Is there anything wrong in this shader code?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, sfml

Code of rippleShader.frag file:

```
// attibutes from vertShader.vert
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

// uniforms
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uTime;

void main() {
    float coef = sin(gl_FragCoord.y * 0.1 + 1 * uTime);
    vTexCoord.y += coef * 0.03;
    gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);
}
```

Code of vertShader.vert file:

```
#version 110

//varying "out" variables to be used in the fragment shader
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    vColor = gl_Color;
    vTexCoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0).xy;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Please accept my apologies, i can't post the image now. But when i run the program the a error promt as follow:

[image]

Comment: Post the error message as text instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error messages means, that you are not allowed to assign any value to the variable `vTexCoord`, because it is an input to the fragment shader.

Change your code somehow like this:

```
void main() {
    float coef   = sin(gl_FragCoord.y * 0.1 + 1.0 * uTime);
    vec2 texC    = vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y + coef * 0.03);
    gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(uTexture, texC);
}
```

Note, you get the warning message, because you used an integral constant value (`1`), instead of an floating point value (`1.0`).